# DIV in scrartcl (KOMA) not resulting in changes

Tags: margins, koma-script, typearea

I have a `scrartcl` document (KOMA package). I want to change the `DIV`, making my textarea bigger.

I tried

```
\documentclass[DIV=12]{scrartcl}
```

But that does not change anything. 
When I try

```
\usepackage[DIV=12]{typearea}
```

I get

> Option clash for package typearea

I do not understand that. How am I supposed to change the `DIV` in the KOMA class?

That what I load before `\begin{document}`

```
\documentclass[DIV=5]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\textbullet, nosep, wide, 
                 leftmargin=*,
                 before=\vspace{-0.50\baselineskip},
                 after =\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}}


\begin{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only if can not remove package `geometry`:

If you really want to use package `geometry` (e.g. to change the size of one margin) then add option `usegeometry` to the class options:

```
\documentclass[DIV=5,
  usegeometry% <- added
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you can not remove package `geometry` because it is loaded by another package, then you can use `\recalctypearea` to overwrite the changes done by `geometry`:

```
\documentclass[DIV=5]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\recalctypearea
\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're loading the `geometry` package, which overrides the settings made by the class, remove it.

Comment: Unrelated: have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before